# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when trying to build Android App from Unity

Tags: java, android, build, unity-game-engine, classnotfoundexception

I've been getting immediate crashes when trying to build to Android. I've had no problem until I tried to change the bundle ID so we could build a different version of the app. I suspect its something to do with the plugins (its using playhaven among other). The only change I made was changing the bundle id, and since then it crashes immediately upon launch (doesn't even get to the splash screen). I'm not experienced in android dev and its probably something obvious. Any help would be great, this has really tripped me up.

Thanks,

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.evodent.fannex.fgo" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionName="1.5.7.0" android:versionCode="3" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.evodent.fannex.fgo.OverrideExample">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <!-- Example deep link
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="company" android:host="===your app's package name here===" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity"/>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="sensor">
        </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.playhaven.android.view.FullScreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
      <!-- Support FullScreen.createIntent -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <!-- Support Uri.parse -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="playhaven" android:host="localhost" android:pathPattern="/full"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.playhaven.android.push.PushReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="com.playhaven.android"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- This is needed to receive Google Cloud Messaging intents from the system. -->
    <receiver android:name="com.playhaven.android.push.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        <category android:name="com.evodent.fannex.fgo"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <!-- This is needed to receive Google Cloud Messaging intents from the system. -->
  <!-- <permission android:name="com.evodent.fannex.fgo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.evodent.fannex.fgo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/> -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false"/>
</manifest>
```

Logcat results

```
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1522): screenshot: sw=180, sh=320, minZ=0, maxZ=21020
I/ActivityManager( 1904): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.evodent.fannex.fgo/.OverrideExample bnds=[14,163][127,322]} from pid 13450
I/libblt_hw( 1522): Library opened (handle = 0, fd = 28)
I/ActivityManager( 1904): Start proc com.evodent.fannex.fgo for activity com.evodent.fannex.fgo/.OverrideExample: pid=4034 uid=10167 gids={3003, 1015, 1006}
D/OpenGLRenderer(13450): Flushing caches (mode 1)
D/OpenGLRenderer(13450): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/AndroidRuntime( 4034): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 4034): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a96210)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.evodent.fannex.fgo/com.evodent.fannex.fgo.OverrideExample}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.evodent.fannex.fgo.OverrideExample
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.evodent.fannex.fgo.OverrideExample
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4034):    ... 11 more
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1522): screenshot: sw=180, sh=320, minZ=0, maxZ=21025
W/ActivityManager( 1904):   Force finishing activity com.evodent.fannex.fgo/.OverrideExample
I/libblt_hw( 1522): Library opened (handle = 5, fd = 25)
I/libblt_hw( 1522): Library closed (handle = 1, fd = 26)
W/ActivityManager( 1904): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41e81790 com.evodent.fannex.fgo/.OverrideExample}
I/libblt_hw( 1522): Library opened (handle = 1, fd = 26)
```

Comment: Did you change Bundle Identifier on Building Settings. And did you change package name on your native file jar?

Comment: wheres the native file jar?

Comment: Where is this come from ~~> OverrideExample

Comment: I'm not sure, I inherited the project. Can I updated the bundle id in the jar file without having to recompile the bundle? I'm not sure I have access to the original source.

Comment: I found it, but its in a Jar, I'm trying to update the OverrideExample.class to reflect the new name. I'm changing the jar's file structure as well as it has to match the class. I'll let you know if it works, thanks for your help

Comment: the compiled jar file containing OverrideExample needed to be updated. I unpacked the jar, changed the directory structure and updated the .class file and it worked. Thanks for the help, it let me down the right path.

Comment: Great job! :). Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a plugin that had been compiled under the old bundle_id. I unzipped the jar, used a java class editor to change the name and directory within the class to match the new bundle id, then updated the jar folders to match this as well eg (company / name / OverrideExample.Class ). Then I re-jar'd the new directories and class file and it worked.